# How to save files from Incoming email using imap_tools into AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, django, email, imap, imap-tools

I have an email server hosted on AWS EC2. I am using [imap_tools](https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/) for retrieving email content.
when I tried to get the file through the payload, I get this return;

`att.payload              # bytes: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\'`

Please how do I get the actual file path from the payload or bytes to be saved on AWS S3 and be able to read it from my table?

I can attach a file to my mail and save it on S3 but getting the attached file coming to a mail address is my challenge.

This is a function for reading email contents with imap_tools

```
def imap_inbox(self):
        unread_inbox = []
      
        for msg in self.mailbox.fetch():
            attachments = []
            for att in msg.attachments:
                attachments += [{
                    "filename": att.filename,         
                    "content_type": att.content_type,
                    "file": att.payload,
                }]
                
            msg_dict = {
                "subject": msg.subject.replace("***UNCHECKED*** ", ""),
                "from_mail": msg.from_,
                "to_mail": msg.to[0], 
                "message": msg.text, 
                "attachments": attachments,    
            }

            if 'RECENT' in msg.flags:
                unread_inbox += [msg_dict]

        return {
            "unread_inbox": unread_inbox,
        }
```

This is my function for mail_server_inbox

```
 def mail_server_inbox(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # imap authentication
        ad_imap = self.authenticate_imap()
        inbox = ad_imap.imap_inbox()
        unread_inbox = inbox.get("unread_inbox")

        for msg in unread_inbox:
            mail_instance = None
            file_name = None
            try:
                attachments = msg.pop("attachments", [])
                msg = { 
                    **msg, 
                }

                attachments = list(
                    map(
                        lambda att: {
                            **att, 
                            
                        },
                        attachments,
                    )
                )
                # saving the attachments in the Documents table
                Document.objects.bulk_create(list(
                    map(lambda att: Document(**att), attachments)
                ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "actual file path from of payload" in email.

Just name, nesting level and some few attachment attrs.

Comment: please is there a way for me to save the file coming from email on AWS S3 bucket?